# Create provision profile for other devs app

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a developer creating my an iOS app, and they shipped me the IPA, but not a provisional profile, and won't be back until January 3 for vacation.

Is there anyway to create a profile in my dev account for it?  I made an AppID and setup an AdHoc provisional profile and it still won't install.  It copies to the device, at the last bit when it goes to "install" it says it "failed to install".

I am not sure if they will respond to before January 3rd when they get back, but I would like to check out the demo before then.  I assume there is no way to install it without a profile.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the codesign utility from the Terminal command-line to re-sign the .app bundle with your own Certificate and Ad Hoc provision file (try a wildcard one).

Answer (score 0):

If they sent you the Xcode project as well, you could recreate the app and codesign it yourself. That should work.

Comment: No I do not have the code yet, I just have an .ipa which is a demo level of the project.